# Selecting a specific type of file in android

Tags: android, android-intent, file-manager

I am trying to make an app where the user can select a file using the android device's file manager. Here is the code that I am using :

```
 boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
                    if (isKitKat)
                    {
                        Intent uploadIntent = new Intent();
                        uploadIntent.setType("*/*");
                        uploadIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(uploadIntent, REPORT_USING_FILE_MANAGER);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Intent uploadIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        uploadIntent.setType("*/*");
                        startActivityForResult(uploadIntent, REPORT_USING_FILE_MANAGER);
                    }
```

I only want the user to be able to select an image file (.jpg, .png etc) or a .pdf file. How can I set this restriction ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are using `loadIntent.setType("*/*");` where you are selecting files of all types.

You have to filter it using MIME type.

For instance, if you wish to choose jpeg files then

```
loadIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
```

Some MIME Types are as follows,

```
image/jpeg
audio/mpeg4-generic
text/html
audio/mpeg
audio/aac
audio/wav
audio/ogg
audio/midi
audio/x-ms-wma
video/mp4
video/x-msvideo
video/x-ms-wmv
image/png
image/jpeg
image/gif
.xml ->text/xml
.txt -> text/plain
.cfg -> text/plain
.csv -> text/plain
.conf -> text/plain
.rc -> text/plain
.htm -> text/html
.html -> text/html
.pdf -> application/pdf
.apk -> application/vnd.android.package-archive
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: which Type i use for  Excel file

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement "photoPickerIntent" for image file

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

After that the following should be done:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                    System.out.println(selectedImage.toString() + "-" + selectedImage.getPath());

                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                    imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```